# Why does my removeTransition function not work?

Tags: javascript, html, css, function, event-handling

I am working a JavaScript Drum Kit. The program works fine, except after the key is pressed and the transition and sound are produced, the key does not return to its initial look, the transition is not removed.
A JavaScript function `removeTransition(e)` is provided for this purpose but it still doesn't work. why?

```
function playSound(e) {
    const audio = document.querySelector(`audio[data-key="${e.keyCode}"]`);
    const key = document.querySelector(`div[data-key="${e.keyCode}"]`);
    if (!audio)
        return;
    key.classList.add('playing');
    audio.currentTime = 0;
    audio.play();
}

function removeTransition(e) {
    if (e.propertyName !== "transform")
        return;
    e.target.classList.remove('playing');
}

window.addEventListener('keydown', playSound);

const keys = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.key'));
keys.forEach(key => {
    key.addEventListener('transitionend', removeTransition);
});
```

I have used the browser developer tools, and `transitionend` was not listed as one of the event listeners. I do not know why?

Comment: I don't think we can tell from what is shown. Have you tried some debugging? e.g. what is contained in keys? Are you running the JS after all the HTML is loaded?

Comment: Your code works fine in isolation. Note that `keyCode` is deprecated and should not be used at all. Use the `key` property instead. Here's working example, making some assumptions about your CSS and also without the audio as we don't have access to your files: https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/9mzg3jnt/

Comment: Thank you @AHaworth I checked and yes the JS file was linked to the HTML in the head section of the page. This caused the JS to load after the HTML. I did the needful, ensuring the HTML is loaded completely before JS is run